# Omitting Excerpt Section of Tag Wiki Blanks Out Entire Tag Wiki

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki

Someone was editing the [Tag Wiki for jRuby](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jruby/info), and it came out blank when I approved the edit. Looks like the Excerpt section is required; if it is left out, the Body section is still there in the edits history, but it is not shown in the Tag Wiki.

Comment: I think the only correct thing to do is require a user to enter the excerpt. The tricky thing is that we can accept a wiki body and not the excerpt.

Comment: @Waffles: Sounds right to me, if the excerpt can be pre-populated with the existing one (if present).

Comment: FYI, similar problem [raised on SU](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2063/tag-info-not-showing). I'd also add that a proposed edit seems to show up as two entries (one for body, one for excerpt) and I've seen at least one case (edits [133](http://superuser.com/edit-suggestions/133) and [134](http://superuser.com/edit-suggestions/134)) that resulted in the excerpt being rejected but the body accepted - thus triggering this error.

Comment: I ran into this problem as well. Any kind of warning would have worked for me, even that ghostly tag text :)

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this, we now validate that the excerpt is not blank when suggested.

There is a slight edge condition:

If somebody submits a tag wiki edit for a blank wiki and only the wiki body is accepted (wiki excerpt rejected) the wiki will still appear blank. No information is lost in this case, and the next editor will see the body.

However, there is no longer a way for regular users to blank out a tag wiki (unless they have full tag wiki edit privs and decide to roll back the excerpt)