# Were my tag wiki suggestions rejected (AKA: Do blank tag excerpts result in tag wikis not showing up)?

Tags: support, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

I'd submitted 4 tag wiki suggestions (excerpt and wiki) for tags [ora-06512](/questions/tagged/ora-06512) & [ora-00911](/questions/tagged/ora-00911).

In both the cases ( https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ora-06512/info, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ora-00911 ) - I'm not sure if the excerpts were approved or not. The behaviour of the tag wiki and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78032/omitting-excerpt-section-of-tag-wiki-blanks-out-entire-tag-wiki) seems to point out that the tag wiki excerpt were rejected.

If they were rejected - can I know why?

If they were not - why are the tag wikis coming up as blank?

[image: ora-06512 tag wiki]

[image: ora-00911 tag wiki]

---

[image: tag wiki on edit]

Comment: @JeremyBanks - Thanks for the link - I'm surprised at the excerpts being rejected. The excerpts tell what the error is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I approved one of the excerpts, but I wasn't enthusiastic about it. It was more so that the wiki body (which is nice, thanks for those) would show up (as you mention, [wikis without an excerpt are effectively invisible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78032/omitting-excerpt-section-of-tag-wiki-blanks-out-entire-tag-wiki)) than because I thought the excerpt was good.

An excerpt is supposed to indicate what the tag is about. This excerpt doesn't give me a clue, it lacks context:

> ORA-00911: invalid character

Oh, it's an Oracle error message? Then do say so!

> [Oracle database error code ORA-00911: invalid character](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/101648)

Comment: Thanks, Gilles. In hindsight, I was biased owing to the fact that I knew that it's an Oracle error code and I agree it lacks context.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your wiki edits were approved ([ORA-00911](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/101456), [ORA-06512](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/101572)) and both of your wiki excerpt edits were rejected ([ORA-00911](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/101457), [ORA-06512](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/101573)). That unfixed edge case of that bug you linked seems responsible for the wikis not showing up.

I'm just guessing, but I suspect they were rejected because they are uncommonly specific as tags go. There are relatively few tags about specific errors, and particularly few for error codes (though [I see that there are *tons* of **ora-*** tags already](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ora-*)).

Your wiki edits were probably approved because people didn't want to reject the useful content, but people felt less bad about rejecting the excerpts.

*edit*: I found a relevant older discussion: [Do we really need a tag for every error code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66352/do-we-really-need-a-tag-for-every-error-code). There doesn't seem to be a strong consensus. That's may be why you received the mix of acceptance and rejection.

Comment: Nice find.. Sathya - you can ask the people who rejected by posting comment on one of their older posts then deleting this comment after they answer, or couple of days without answer which means they don't want to answer which is also fine.

Comment: @Jeremy Aye, I'm aware of that discussion - and I agree with OMGPonies' answer there, hence my edits.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I could do that - except that I couldn't get a permalink to the suggested tag wiki edit approval summary screen and hence didn't know if it was approved/rejectd and by whom

Comment: Good point.. I think that right after suggesting, you can see the link and save it somewhere then come back later and visit the link to see the fate of your suggestion.

Comment: @ShadowWizard unfortunately it doesn't come - as a reviewer you can save it, if you're suggesting an edit, it'll be in your activity but for tag wiki there's no such link