# Why doesn't my tag wiki edit show up?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I recently made a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9227800/revisions) on a new tag [zfdatagrid](/questions/tagged/zfdatagrid). As far as I can see it has been [approved](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/198949), but the tag still shows as having [no wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zfdatagrid/info).

When will the new wiki show up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag wiki shows up now.

An excerpt is required for the tag wiki to be shown. The edit help does say:

> The tag wiki excerpt is a brief plain text introduction to the topic that the tag represents. It is shown at the top of tag question lists, and as a tooltip wherever the tag appears. **Complete this first!**

Under normal circumstances, an empty excerpt cannot be submitted, but there is an edge case mentioned in the answer to:
[Omitting Excerpt Section of Tag Wiki Blanks Out Entire Tag Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78032/omitting-excerpt-section-of-tag-wiki-blanks-out-entire-tag-wiki)

Your [suggested excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/198950) was rejected, but the full wiki was accepted, so you fell into the edge condition mentioned there.

(I just copied one sentence from your tag wiki to the excerpt, feel free to improve on it.)

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly the excerpt I suitted but it was rejected :)

Comment: It's not. Your suggested excerpt was "Data grid for Zend Framework", which is a bit on the short side. (Not saying how it is now is perfect either.)

Comment: Sorry. Reading this on my iPhone and was looking at my original excerpt! Duh.