# Why does the system pretend there's no wiki for a tag when only the excerpt is missing?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-wiki

I stumbled upon the [sortedmap](/questions/tagged/sortedmap) tag on Stack Overflow today and wanted to add a [source](http://www.cs.rit.edu/usr/local/jdk/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), probably because I'm anal like that.

If you look at the tag, it says:

> There is no tag wiki for this tag … yet!

However, if you look at the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12098670/revisions), or go to [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/39456), there's a big chunk of text there.

The "Save Edits" button for this tag is currently disabled, but I've checked other tag wikis and the "Save Edits" button is enabled.  Entering an "Edit Summary" doesn't enable the button either.

Is this a bug, a feature for newly created tag wikis that I can't find here on Meta, or something else?

Comment: The tag appears to think it has an excerpt instead of a wiki (its "show excerpt" button is enabled), when it's the other way around...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The suggested excerpt for that tag wiki [was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/560587), but the tag wiki content *itself* was approved. Tag wikis [must have excerpts before their full content will be displayed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78032/omitting-excerpt-section-of-tag-wiki-blanks-out-entire-tag-wiki/80153#80153).

Filling out the excerpt field will allow you to submit changes to the body as well. As long as the excerpt is approved, everything will show up as expected.

Comment: You're right; I didn't even see that the tag wiki excerpt was blank.  I forget that even though you fill them out in the same form, they seem to be treated as separate objects.

Comment: Ah, is that why there are so many tags where the wiki text is the exact same thing as the excerpt? Seems counterproductive. "Let's not display any information until this has been summarized." But how will someone summarize it if they can't tell it's even there to be summarized?

Comment: I was just looking for a relevant FAQ entry so that I could turn your "Tag wikis must have excerpts before their full content will be displayed." sentence into a link. Turns out [there is no MSO `[faq]` for tag wikis](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=tag+wiki+[faq]) (yet).

Comment: @animuson I guess the expectation was that it was less likely for excerpts to be rejected than the bodies, so in general this would be a non-issue. I'm not sure on the numbers of how that plays out in practice, though.

Comment: @PopularDemand Unacceptable! I did add a link for your referential convenience, though.