# Why is this thrice-approved wiki-edit not visible?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

2 month ago, I added a new tag and edited its wiki:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1286347

I received 3 approvals. Yet, it is still not visible:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog-toplevel/info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the tag wiki is not visible because there isn't an excerpt. I suggested an edit to add it, and this is what I see.

[image: screenshot]

It still is a bug, indeed.

Comment: [and it's been around for a while, too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80153/148949)

Comment: Thanks for the edit! What is odd is that the excerpt and full wiki history seem to be separated. It would also help to show suggestions within history.

Answer (score 7):

There <strike>is</strike> *was* no tag wiki excerpt for the tag; if the tag wiki doesn't have an excerpt, the wiki itself doesn't show either.

It appears your excerpt [was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1286348#./1286348?&_suid=1362411608953012091716687395321), and to be honest, I see why.

**Edit:** And now that the excerpt has been approved, the wiki now shows as well.

Comment: I understand that excerpt being rejected, but what about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1286347)?

Comment: @DavidRobinson - I'm not sure what you mean. Tag wikis are strange creatures; you have one form to fill out the excerpt and the wiki, and yet they get reviewed separately (and you get reputation from both edits), but then they're apparently treated as one joined object in that you have to have the excerpt to show the wiki. In any case, it appears the same wiki excerpt has been approved now, and I see the tag.

Comment: @DavidRobinson & LBT: It would help if you both would avoid allusions and instead state clearly what the actual reason for rejection was.

Comment: @false: Did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1286348)?

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Now, still an allusion. And, no I did not see that comment at all when I went through my activities/suggestions.

Comment: @false: I don't really know what you mean by an allusion. You mean a link? (Should I have copied the text from that link into my comment- would that have made it less of an allusion?)

Comment: @false - sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.  The rejection reasons were pretty clear, as the excerpt didn't seem clear or helpful, and included markup tags that wouldn't appear properly in the excerpt.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: It is an allusion to avoid to state the (to you) obvious: No highlighting in excerpts.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: The rejection reasons were not visible in the edit. The only clue were 3 approvals nothing else.